# how to count the rows with blank cells in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm a user of vb.net 2008 and currently developing a system for our department. I need your help regarding to count rows which have empty cells in datagridview. The count of rows must be displayed in a label.

Here's my code.

```
For i = 0 To dgvMonitoringBoard.Rows.Count - 1
    If dgvMonitoringBoard.Rows(i).Cells(24).Value.ToString = " " Then
        x += 1
    End If
Next

lblForTransfer.Text = "Items for transfer to Purchasing:" & x
```

Comment: You're code work, just replace `" "` with `""` ... no empty space. I hope so You define that `x` somewhere before `for..next` loop. Or You can use `If Len(dgvMonitoringBoard.Rows(i).Cells(24).Value.ToString.Trim)=0 Then ... Next` , but, if field value is `null` error will raise.

Comment: i have declared the x in the top for..next loop as Dim x as integer = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little different approach than @equisde. I would use `Linq` for your case. This will return the count of how many rows either have a `DBNull.Value` **or** an empty string...

**Here's a one liner...**

```
 Dim count As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Where(Function(r) r.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToList.Any(Function(c) c.Value Is DBNull.Value OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(c.Value).Trim))).Count
```

**Here's top down - Sometime's easier to read...**

```
   Dim count As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow) _
                          .Where(Function(r) r.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToList _
                          .Any(Function(c) c.Value Is DBNull.Value _
                          OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(c.Value).Trim))).Count
```

**Then you can do...**

```
 lblForTransfer.Text = "Items for transfer to Purchasing: " & count.ToString
```

**Side Note:** Try to not use `+` for string concatenation use the `&` for string concatenation. You can put this in a function as well and pass the `DataGridView` into it that way you can re-use it anywhere you would need and return the value.

**UPDATE PER REQUEST**

Here is a shared function I wrote that takes a `DataGridView` object and an optional column index to do the searching for you. This function can be used anywhere you would like to use it... Note: This will also exclude new rows if you have `Allow Adding Rows` to **True**, if it's not allowed it doesn't matter.

```
  Public Shared Function EmptyCount(ByVal dgrid As DataGridView, Optional ByVal intColumn As Integer = -1) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    If dgrid IsNot Nothing AndAlso dgrid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If intColumn >= 0 Then 'Specific Column...
            If intColumn <= dgrid.Columns.Count Then
                count = dgrid.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Where(Function(rs) Not rs.IsNewRow) _
                    .Select(Function(r) r.Cells(intColumn)).Where(Function(r) r.Value Is DBNull.Value _
                     OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(r.Value))).Count
            End If
        Else 'Any columns...
            count = dgrid.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Where(Function(rs) Not rs.IsNewRow) _
                     .Where(Function(r) r.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToList _
                     .Any(Function(c) c.Value Is DBNull.Value _
                     OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(c.Value).Trim))).Count
        End If
    End If

    Return count
End Function
```

**Usage Example**

```
 'Include all columns...
 lblForTransfer.Text = "Items for transfer to Purchasing: " & EmptyCount(YOURDATAGRIDVIEWNAME).ToString

 'Specific column...
 lblForTransfer.Text = "Items for transfer to Purchasing: " & EmptyCount(YOURDATAGRIDVIEWNAME, 24).ToString
```

Comment: the code works, but it doesn't display the right count of rows.. :( how can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `the code works, but not displaying the right count of rows`?  Please give more details? This will return how many rows have either dbnull.values and or they are empty...

Comment: it displays a number of rows but it doesn't give me the right count. well actually the counting of empty cells is based in columns . for example I have transferdateToPur column and i want to count the empty cells of that column.

Comment: Thats different then what you have requested. `I need your help regarding to count rows which have empty cells in datagridview. ` that was the question. If you want to check a specific column, code of course would need to be altered.

Comment: Well I'm sorry about that :(

Comment: @jen no it's fine, but what you are requesting wasn't the original. Give me a few minute's and will update... :)

Comment: Alright. Thanks then. :) I'm a newbie here in stackoverflow that's why I gave the wrong request. :(

Comment: @jen please see update. It's a function you can place where you want, pass in a `DataGridView` object and an optional column index you want to check for `DBNull.Value` **or** `String.Empty`. I hope this clear's things up!

Comment: hello! thanks for the update. i tried your updated post, it displays 0 . How does it work?

Comment: Are you doing this in a click event?

Comment: Where ever you want to display it. I provided an example. You have to pass in the datagridview and a column index if u want otherwise it will look at all column...

Comment: YES. I'm doing it in click event. why?

Comment: Use the second example i provided. You have to have at least 1 row in the datagridview otherwise theres no condition to check...

Comment: Copy the whole function and put in your class... then use it like the example... but put in your click event.

Answer (score 1):

The below code loops through the DataGridView rows and cells. If any empty cell is found on any row, the counter increases for counting the number of rows with an empty cell.

```
  Dim countRows as Integer = 0        
    For Each dgvRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvMonitoringBoard.Rows  'NOTE: Use dgvMonitoringBoard.Rows - 1  if AllowUserToAddRows property is set to True
        For Each dgvCell As DataGridViewCell In dgvRow.Cells
            If dgvCell.Value = "" Then
                countRows += 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

   lblForTransfer.Text = "Items for transfer to Purchasing: " + countRows.ToString
```

Comment: If the `dgvCell.Value` is null this would fail as the comparison isn't the same, maybe you forgot to check this condition? Other than that good solution.